# Closing messages and tagging questions by difficulty

Tags: discussion

I view this site as using/understanding *Mathematica* at a high level. I'm sure that many people do not have such a high level, especially when they/we are starting, and sometimes ask pretty trivial questions.

Could it be interesting create a label or something like this, to tag these questions as [easy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easy) or [pretty-trivial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pretty-trivial)? I ask this, because many times trivial questions and excellent answers may help other newcomers, and may avoid that the question will be asked again by other people.

Another issue: Is it possible to post your own work on this site, only for comments or to give thanks to people that helped to do that work?

Comment: I am also not sure if I understand everything you say correctly. Do you feel for example that the closing message "This question arises due to a simple mistake such as a trivial syntax error..." is not so nice, or perhaps that it is used too often (instead of using a more specific closing message)? It is interesting to think about an "easy" tag, but there are some downsides, like offending people, or that tags are now used to divide by subject rather than by level.

Comment: A major problem with tagging questions according to difficulty level is that this evaluation is subjective. Nobody knows everything about *Mathematica* and every possible subject area in which it is used, so there will be "easy" questions for one person that are "hard" for another. This being the case, it's probably better to let people make their own assessments than to attempt to categorize the content in general terms.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand your questions, but going with what I can make of them, here are my answers.

1. StackExchange, in general, has a policy of preserving strong answers for posterity even if they were given in reply to a weak question. *Mathematica*.SE operates in accordance with this policy.
2. Please don't post questions that are just for comment. This not a forum. We want to focus on meaningful, well-posed, technical questions that will provoke thoughtful and detailed answers covering material not already available in the *Mathematica* Documentation Center.
3. Also, please do not edit a question or write an answer just to thank the people who have contributed to answering one of your questions. These will surely be deleted. It is OK to express thanks in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I endorse everything m_goldberg has said. This site is definitely open for business for new and inexperienced Mathematica users. We have a whole page of answers to the question [“What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new Mathematica users?”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/8) which deals with a lot of common issues. Supposedly “easy” questions can indeed be useful teaching moments, and we welcome questions that lend themselves to those kinds of answers. (Personally, they are the kinds of answers I most enjoy writing.)

But we *do* expect that site users, beginners or otherwise, make some effort in their questions, for example by posting the code that isn't working how they want, and explaining clearly what errors they are getting. We also expect that people at least try to search the documentation before posting here. Mathematica’s documentation is far from perfect, but it is quite comprehensive. We close questions that have arisen because of a simple syntax mistake or that could have been answered with a simple search of the documentation. We do this because we don’t think these kinds of questions are going to be much use to future visitors.

m_goldberg is quite right: do not post questions or answers just to thank people. That is not how this site works. Here is what you *can* do, though:

- If you have some (not too long) code that works but you think can be improved somehow, you are welcome to post the code, and ask “How can this be improved?”. You will need to say what you mean by “improved”, though (faster, more concise, more functional style, no `For` loops etc). I think this might be what you mean by to post “only for comment”.
- If you have a nice solution to a problem, it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, and share your knowledge Q&A-style. For some examples of this, see a few self-answered questions that I posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/how-can-i-manipulate-temporaldata), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9109/8) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17125/8).

Comment: ok @Verbeia I have any code to improve and I don´t want to disturb, so... I didn´t post it.... but "how to improve could be a way of asking for this case. I like your comment, but I´m afraid to asking because I don´t want neither being blocked again nor disturb the moderators and colleagues of SE.

Comment: @MikaIke - you don't need to be afraid. It is simply a matter of understanding why (the edited version of) [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27439/8) got 5 up votes and [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45795/8) got downvoted.

Comment: ok we are seeing... :-) on the fly... but please, if I posted badly warning me before blocking, and I pay attention to up/down votes